# How to constantly detect nearby marker locations from current location in Google Maps android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am trying to display a `TextView` at the top left corner of Google Maps that inform users if they are x distances from particular marker point locations, i.e. "You are close to location A", but only display the `TextView` if within range. If they move out of range, the `TextView` will disappear.

I understand that the Google Places API shows you all the nearby locations, but I only want to show nearby locations of the markers I have on the map if users are x distances close to them.

How can I achieve this? Would I still need to use Google Places API?

my class .java:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

private LatLng currLocation;

private static final LatLng POINTA = new LatLng(32.820193, -117.232568);
private static final LatLng POINTB = new LatLng(32.829129, -117.232204);
private static final LatLng POINTC = new LatLng(32.821114, -117.231534);
private static final LatLng POINTD = new LatLng(32.825157, -117.232003);

// Array to store hotspot coordinates
private ArrayList<LatLng> markerCoords = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
private static final int POINTS = 4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Create MenuInflater object to insert ActionBar buttons
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    // Display the ActionBar buttons from .xml
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded()
{
    if (mMap == null)
    {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null)
        {
            markerCoords.add(POINTA);
            markerCoords.add(POINTB);
            markerCoords.add(POINTC);
            markerCoords.add(POINTD);

            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
private void setUpMap()
{
    // Set My Location blue dot
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (myLocation != null)
    {
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        currLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; i++)
    {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(markerCoords.get(i))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.post_it_marker)));
    }
}
```

map.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraTargetLat="32.881416"
        map:cameraTargetLng="-117.237428"
        map:cameraZoom="15"
        map:mapType="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this problem as i'm facing the same challenge?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer `location.distanceTo(anotherLocation)`

In setupMap i recommend to add additional listener, to get all location changes in a simple way.

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

Then in this listener you just take distance between current location and your targets. Distance in meters.

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    Location target = new Location("target");
    for(LatLng point : new LatLng[]{POINTA, POINTB, POINTC, POINTD}) {
        target.setLatitude(point.latitude);
        target.setLongitude(point.longitude);
        if(location.distanceTo(target) < METERS_100) {
            // bingo!
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you should make your activity `implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener`

Comment: I'm getting an error with reference to `this` stating "setOnMyLocationChangeListener cannot be applied to this"

Comment: @Pangu come on, it's easy fixing with android studio. just make your activity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener. i updated my answer

Comment: @pengrad...I apologize I am new to android :( ....I will try this and let you know very soon!

Comment: @Pangu yeah, let's close this post :)

Comment: there seems to be a minor issue, when I log the distance between location and the target, it returns x meters, but converting it to miles gives me a distance that is 1.4 miles less than what google maps on my browser shows...do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: it's a direct line distance, and on the google maps - route distance