# How to find a list of nearby markers in google maps

Tags: php, android, google-maps

Hello friends i am making a cab booking app. so if my rider want to checkout a list of drivers nearby him.  How it could be done in google maps ?
 Here i am using this codes.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mlastLocation = location;
   Location target = new Location("target");
    for(ServiceData data:list) {
        target.setLatitude(data.location.latitude);
        target.setLongitude(data.location.longitude);
        if(location.distanceTo(target) < _METER_) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "driver found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "driver is too far.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    sendlocationToserver();


}
```

by using these codes i am able to find only a single driver but if i want a list of drivers any idea? how it could be done?

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284708/how-to-constantly-detect-nearby-marker-locations-from-current-location-in-google?rq=1) if it can help you :)

Comment: sir i already fixed this problem btw thanks.